# Incrementally creating a 100k+ lines file with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bigdata

I want to export some data from our App Engine app - the current data set is around 70k (will grow) entities which need to be filtered.

The filtering is done with a cron job (app engine task), 1k batch at a time. Is there a mechanism which will allow me to add lines to an existing file, rather than uploading it in bulk (like Google Cloud Storage requires)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) to access the Datastore from your own PC or a Compute Engine instance and write all the entities to your hard drive (or Compute Engine instance). It's different from using the Datastore from within the App Engine instances, but only slightly, so you should have no problems writing the code.

I must observe, however, that writing 100 files to the Cloud Storage with 1,000 entities in each sounds like a good solution to me. Whatever you want to do with these records later, having 100 smaller files instead of one large super-file may be a good idea.